# How to use select2 with multiple options using Razor and MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am trying to create a multiple choice list using Select2, Razor and the MVC framework. My problem is that the object in the controller that receives the array input is always null. The front-end looks as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="@Url.Action(MVC.Configurazione.Contatori.Edit())">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select class="form-control attributoSelect2" name="attributiSelezionati" value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati">
                <option value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati" selected>@Model.AttributoDescrizione</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The action method "Edit", is the controller method that receives the array of chosen items from the drop-down list.

The Javascript is the following:

```
    $('.attributoSelect2').select2({
        placeholder: "Search attribute",
        multiple: true,
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 150,
            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Configurazione.Attributi.SearchAttrubutes())",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    search: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data.map(function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.Id,
                            text: item.Description
                        };
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

And finally the C# controller has an object that is expected to retrieve the data from the view and is defined:

```
public string[] AttributiSelezionati { get; set; }
```

and the HttpPost method that receives the data is:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model) { }
```

Could someone give me some insight into what I am doing wrong and the areas that I should change in order to find the problem?

Comment: You're using multiple select with `select2`, right? Why not use `ListBoxFor` or `multiple` attribute on the select element?

Comment: But I am using the "multiple: true" flag in Javascript, this is the reason why I am not using it in the view. I am not sure how to use ListBoxFor but I am currently looking into some documentation for this and will update you when I make progress. Thank you.

Comment: Is that `<option>` content containing all option values from AJAX? Try to assign `name` attribute with matching case, e.g. `name="AttributiSelezionati"`. Also you're assigning default value by `value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati"` which has `string[]` array type instead of `string`.

Comment: @Razvan, you want to send array of string that is from Select2 to your controller action method right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to send the selected items to the controller action method

Answer (score 0):

you class name error  not attributoSelect2  is  attributesSelect2  , I also make this mistake often. haha

```
 <select class="form-control attributoSelect2" name="attributiSelezionati" value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati">
                <option value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati" selected>@Model.AttributoDescrizione</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't fix the issue. My problem is that I don't understand how the data binding between the view and the controller works. Can you notice something obviously wrong that I am missing related to how I am sending the data to the server?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reason for not being receiving data on server. First of all you need to change your select code as follow

```
@Html.DropDownList("attributiSelezionati", Model.AttributiSelezionati, new { @class = "form-control attributo select2" })
```

now go to console in browser and get the data of element to confirm that your code properly works in HTML & JS

After that you need to add attribute at your controller's action method as

```
[OverrideAuthorization]
[HttpPost]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach that has been used in some of our projects without any problem:

***View:***

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select")

$(document).ready(function () {

    var student = $("#StudentId");

    //for Select2 Options: https://select2.github.io/options.html
    student.select2({
        language: "tr",//don't forget to add language script (select2/js/i18n/tr.js)
        minimumInputLength: 0, //for listing all records > set 0
        maximumInputLength: 20, //only allow terms up to 20 characters long         
        multiple: false,
        placeholder: "Select",
        allowClear: true,
        tags: false, //prevent free text entry
        width: "100%",

        ajax: {
            url: '/Grade/StudentLookup',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    query: params.term, //search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                var newData = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    newData.push({
                            //id part present in data 
                            id: item.Id,     
                            //string to be displayed
                            text: item.Name + " " + item.Surname
                    });
                });
                return { results: newData };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }
    });


    //You can simply listen to the select2:select event to get the selected item
    student.on('select2:select', onSelect)

    function onSelect(evt) {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }

        //Event example for close event
        student.on('select2:close', onClose)

        function onClose(evt) {
            console.log('Closed…');
        } 
});
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult StudentLookup(string query)
{
    var students = repository.Students.Select(m => new StudentViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name,
        Surname = m.Surname
    })
    //if "query" is null, get all records
    .Where(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || m.Name.StartsWith(query)) 
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name);
    return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope this helps...

**Update:**

***Dropdown option groups:***

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group Name">
    <option>Nested option</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

For more information have a look at https://select2.org/options.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This is what I was looking for, some template showing how this can be done. However, I must use a multiple choice drop-down list with values that a grouped together (by Id) and when I choose one from one group all other items (from the same group) become disabled. Do you have any idea how to obtain this?

Comment: This is one example of what I am trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/hpkqxto6/